# Shift+F8 changes letter case for 2 letters; how to unmap this?

Tags: key-bindings

`setcolors.vim` of [vim's Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes#Script) defines these keybindings:

```
"   F8                next scheme
"   Shift-F8          previous scheme
"   Alt-F8            random scheme
```

but when I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (the other two work fine) vim just changes the case of the 2 letters on and exactly after the cursor.
Running `:map` I see

```
  <S-F8>      * :call NextColor(-1)<CR>
```

so why am I getting this change-2-character-case behavior?

Second, I tried to unmap Shift-F8 by running `:unmap ^[[32~` obtaining `^[[32~` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, but this did not work.

So how do get the desired behavior, getting the previous color scheme with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>?

**Update** + PS: I use vim in `urxvt`/`tmux`.

I created another user account in my machine (linux), logged in and run vim on a virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) and I get the same behavior with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, and clearly, I have no vim plugins there, and no `tmux` either(!).

Next, in my account instead of running `urxvt`+`tmux`+`vim` I run `xterm`+`vim`, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> works just fine! Then I run `xterm`+`tmux`+`vim` but now <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> changes 4 characters instead of 2!

So it should be a terminal/`tmux` related issue and not a vim issue. I have not managed to find what causes the problem though and how to fix it though...

**Update after comments**

`echo $TERM` is `xterm-256color` in:

- `xterm`,
- `urxvt`,
- `tmux` inside `urxvt` or `xterm`,
- `vim`, running `:!echo $TERM` inside every one of the above.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and immediately after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> produces:

- `^[[19;2~` in `xterm` or in`vim` inside `xterm`
- `^[[34~` in `tmux` inside `xterm` or in `vim` inside `tmux` inside `xterm`, and
- `^[[32~` in `urxvt` or in `tmux` inside `urxvt` or in `vim` inside `tmux` or in `vim` inside `tmux` inside `urxvt`.

In `vim`, `:version` shows `+terminfo` and there is clearly no `+termcap`.

The output of `:set ttybuiltin termcap` differs slightly between:

- [`vim` inside `xterm`](http://pastebin.com/3XvzxEQy) and
- [`vim` inside `tmux` inside `xterm`](http://pastebin.com/u5gjjgmY), which appears the same as in `vim` inside (`tmux`/)`urxvt`.

Comment: Have you tried `:unmap <S-F8> ` ?

Comment: Yes, (typing in exactly every character that you wrote, without any <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>), and the situation remains the same.

Comment: Strange, have you tried `vim -Nu NONE`, creating a mapping for the same key combination, and trying `unmap` again ?

Comment: @nobe4 Thank you, it seems my problem has (almost) nothing to do with vim. If (doubt it) I found a solution will update, till then any hints are welcome.

Comment: A good way to test this is to compare `vim` against `gvim`.  I believe it has something to do with `urxvt`, I can replicate the exact same behaviour in my `urxvt` terminal but it does not happen at all in `gvim`.

Comment: One more thing, the difference between `urxvt` and `xterm` makes sense.  On `urxvt` `<S-F8>` gives me `~` and on `xterm` it gives me `;2~`.

Comment: This is a typical `termcap` / `terminfo` problem.  `Shift-F8` is recognized as such by Vim only if the code produced by the keyboard in the current terminal agrees to the `termcap` / `terminfo` entry for `Shift-F8` for the current `TERM`.  So, what is the output of `echo $TERM` in your `tmux`?  What is the output if you press `Ctrl+V Shift+F8` in the same `tmux`?

Comment: Thank you very much guys, @SatoKatsura and @grochmal; it seems we are close to  a solution, I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Now, what is the output of `infocmp -1 xterm | fgrep -w kf20` (in a terminal)?

Comment: @SatoKatsura It's `kf20=\E[19;2~,` in every combination (`tmux`/`xterm`, `xterm`, `urxvt`, `tmux`/`urxvt`).

Comment: `^[[19;2~` is the same as `\E[19;2~`, so `Shift-F8` is only going to work in `xterm`.  Now, there are two ways to fix this: (1) fix `TERM` in `tmux` and `urxvt`, or (2) fix it only in Vim.  For (1) see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Setting_the_correct_term) for `tmux` (choose the `screen-256color` way), and complain upstream for `urxvt`.  For (2) you can just add `if &term == 'xterm-256color' | map <Esc>[19;2~ <s-F8> | endif` to your vimrc.

Comment: tmux works well enough with urxvt if one doesn't try setting `TERM` to `xterm`, etc.

Comment: @ThomasDickey `tmux` left to its own devices used to inherit `TERM` from the underlying terminal.  IIRC this has changed in version 2.0.

Comment: It's not that simple: tmux reads the terminal description for the original `TERM` and remembers what terminal *capabilities* are defined, passing the equivalent to the client.  (This question is too broad to be answered properly, by the way).

Comment: Same problem for me with the plugin _xolox/vim-colorscheme-switcher_. `:map` outputs `n  <S-F8>      * :PrevColorScheme<CR>` but doesn't work. the plugin use the following commands `inoremap <silent> <S-F8> <C-O>:PrevColorScheme<CR>\n
  nnoremap <silent> <S-F8> :PrevColorScheme<CR>`

Comment: I have this problem too. Really none has found a solution yet?

Comment: This question now has an answer here: [Some function keys switch cases of letters under and after the cursor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/some-function-keys-switch-cases-of-letters-under-and-after-the-cursor)