# Can the ENTER key be made to behave like the RETURN key? Should I do so in vim?

Tags: key-bindings

In `vim`, the numerical <kbd>Enter ⎆</kbd> key behaves differently from the carriage <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd> key.

Is there any practical reason why the numerical <kbd>Enter ⎆</kbd> behaves like that?

Can the numerical <kbd>Enter ⎆</kbd> be made to behave like the carriage <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd> key (including in combination with <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> and if so, how?

Comment: I think `inoremap <kEnter> <enter>` should work.  Check `:help keycodes`

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one, but I'm really not sure what your question is. Do you have two enter keys on your keyboard? What is a "numerical Enter key?" From Tommy A's doc it seems that both `<Enter>` and `<Return>` evaluate to `<CR>`, so I'm not sure how they could be different. Can you please give us a bit more info?

Comment: Both keys behave exactly the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, on a cygwin setup `<c-v><enter>` gives `^M` while `<c-v><num enter>` gives `^[OM` but I don't see any difference in their behavior... I needed you might want to create mappings using `<c-v><key>` to get the behavior you want. For example something like `nnoremap ^[OM ^[`

Comment: Yet another case of messed up `termcap` / `terminfo` entry.  See the discussion [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8461/2313) for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this issue was affecting only the normal mode, it was solved by adding the following lines at the very bottom of my `.vimrc` configuration file:

```
nmap <kEnter> <CR>
nmap <S-kEnter> <S-CR>
```

Apparently, some plugin had messed up the default behaviour.