# Some function keys switch cases of letters under and after the cursor

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-ultisnips, escape

**Foreword**

I use UltiSnips and have the following definitions in my `.vimrc` file

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<F8>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<F8>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<S-F8>"
```

**The problem**

The third definition doesn't work; the strange behavior I witness is that <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> switches the case of the letter under the cursor and that after it and move to the next char just as I had hit <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> in normal mode.

**Troubleshooting**

Mindful of [another strange keyboard behavior I experienced in the bash with fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/1238), I decided to investigate which escape sequence is sent when I press (shifted) function keys, by issuing them in the terminal prepended by <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
What I "discovered" is that <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sends `^[[32~`, which is the same escape sequence sent by <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>, which indeed does the following:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> exits UltiSnips' select mode, thus returning to normal mode
- <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> do nothing since the latter "kills" the former, which doesn't expect a digit after it
- <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> switch the case of under-cursor and immediately-after-cursor letters and moves to next character

which is what I see happening everytime.

Furthermore, I've checked that function keys from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F4</kbd> send `^[[11~ ^[[12~ ^[[13~ ^[[14~` whereas combinations from <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> send `^[[23~ ^[[24~ ^[[25~ ^[[26~`; based on these escape sequences I'd expect all these keys to misbehave (in the same way too, except for the count), but they don't! 
Of the aforementioned 8 combinations, only <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> switches the case of the following 5 letters (as the `^[[5~` escape sequence implies), and the others do nothing (they don't even exit the select mode!).

**Info**

I use URxvt, `$TERM` is `rxvt-unicode-256color` and Vim version is 8.1.

**Related question(s) and pages**

The first time I had this problem was long ago and I searched for an answer already; since then I've forgotted I had found a related (actually exactly the same) [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/shiftf8-changes-letter-case-for-2-letters-how-to-unmap-this) but it was and is still **unanswered** (maybe this is way I've forgotten it).

[Here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim) is a related wikipage.

[Here](https://github.com/vim-vdebug/vdebug/issues/359) is a related issue on GitHub.

Comment: what happens if you do `:set <s-f8>=^[[32~`?  to type this, type `:set <s-f8>=` then press ctrl-v shift-f8.  this should make `<s-f8>` work properly

Comment: With the first shot, man! Can you explain me why is this necessary? After all, the misbehavior of **some** shifted function keys is "coherent" with the sequence they generate. What I mean is that I would have said that `:set <s-f8>=^[[32~` does exactly what is already done. But it's clearly not the case, since your answer works!

Comment: what terminal emulator do you use and what specific version of vim, and what is $TERM?  the very short answer is that vim needs to guess what all the keys are and sometimes guesses wrong, and it's all not completely standardized.  I can probably give more detail in an answer if I knew some more information

Comment: @Mass, added some info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The codes which keys produce varies wildly by terminal.  vim tries to
guess which escape sequences corresponds to which keycodes (`<f1>` etc)
based on the $TERM variable and terminfo.  The shifted f-keys are not
standardized and they do not have termcap/terminfo entries. In this case,
vim falls back to the xterm ones.  Note, wherever `^[` is written, this means a literal escape character.

#### Changing vim's key codes

For many keys, vim has a key code for it of the form `<..>`.  This includes the shifted f-keys, `<s-f1>`..`<s-f37>`.  The way to change this for your terminal is through `set` (the following are equivalent):

```
set <s-f1>=^[[23~
execute "set <s-f1>=\<esc>[23~"
```

Some keys do not have a named key code, such as `<s-enter>`.  In this case, vim provides many extra function keys, up to `<f37>` which you can use, if your terminal supports it.  As usual, you can grab the key code by typing it after <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> or with `cat`.

```
set <f37>=^[OM
execute "set <f37>=\<esc>OM"
```

Then you can use `<f37>` in place of `<s-enter>` whenever you want to use that key.

#### Explaining the original behavior

Below is a list of the keys in urxvt and xterm, produced by running cat in a shell then typing each key (except for f13/f14 which comes from `infocmp`).

In urxvt, <kbd>shift-f1</kbd> and <kbd>shift-f2</kbd> are exactly
  identical to <kbd>f11</kbd> and <kbd>f12</kbd>.  Therefore, by default,
  you cannot use both for different things.  This also explains why
  <kbd>shift-f1</kbd> and <kbd>shift-f2</kbd> did not produce the case
  changing behavior you saw- vim thought they were some other key.

Likewise, <kbd>shift-f4</kbd> in urvt is the same as <kbd>f14</kbd>.
I'm not sure why but vim thinks this is the `<undo>` key, which is `t_&8=^[[26;*~`, close but not quite the same as <kbd>f14</kbd>.

#### Table

```
              urxvt       xterm

f1           ^[[11~       ^[OP
f2           ^[[12~       ^[OQ
f3           ^[[13~       ^[OR
f4           ^[[14~       ^[OS

f5           ^[[15~       ^[[15~
f6           ^[[17~       ^[[17~
f7           ^[[18~       ^[[18~
f8           ^[[19~       ^[[19~

f9           ^[[20~       ^[[20~
f10          ^[[21~       ^[[21~
f11          ^[[23~       ^[[23~
f12          ^[[24~       ^[[24~
f13          ^[[25~
f14          ^[[26~

shift-f1     ^[[23~       ^[[1;2P 
shift-f2     ^[[24~       ^[[1;2Q 
shift-f3     ^[[25~       ^[[1;2R 
shift-f4     ^[[26~       ^[[1;2S 

shift-f5     ^[[28~       ^[[15;2~
shift-f6     ^[[29~       ^[[17;2~
shift-f7     ^[[31~       ^[[18;2~
shift-f8     ^[[32~       ^[[19;2~

shift-f9     ^[[33~       ^[[20;2~
shift-f10    ^[[34~       ^[[21;2~
shift-f11    ^[[23$       ^[[23;2~
shift-f12    ^[[24$       ^[[24;2~
```

Comment: I notice that in the table there are more identical escape sequences than you referred to in *Explaining the original behavior*. Have you just picked some of them for brevity or am I missing something?

Comment: Why is it that I can `map` both `<F10>` and `<F11>` to actions within CGDB's configuration file, but not `<S-F11>`? (Nothing happens.) I am using Ubuntu, and CTRL+V then SHIFT+F11 produces `^[[23;2~`.

Comment: @user2023370 did you do `execute "set <s-f11>=\<esc>[23;2~"` as per the answer above

Comment: @Mass Yes. I see that using either `set <s-f1>=^[[23~` or `execute "set <s-f11>=\<esc>[23;2~"` in `.vimrc` is equivalent; at least `:set termcap` shows the same new entry for `<S-F11>`. Perhaps CGDB's configuration file doesn't support shifted f-keys.

Comment: @Mass, I keep coming to this answer every now and then. Thank you very much!!!